# Extract parts from an Association

Tags: associations

```
as = <|1 -> 2.2, 2 -> 3.4, 3 -> 8.1|>;
```

I don't understand the following:

```
as[[1]]
```

> 2.2

But I expected to see

> <|1 -> 2.2|>

On the other hand:

```
as[[1 ;; 1]]
```

> <|1 -> 2.2|>

Comment: It;s like `as[[{1}]]` and if you have other head than association, it will be kept too.

Comment: When you do `list[[1]]` you don't expect to get a list so why do you expect `association[[1]]` to give an association?

Comment: Right, but one could expect `1->2.2`

Comment: An association is not a list of rules. It's a different animal. Your intuition is correct if you do it on Normal[as].

Answer (score 7):

Probably should be handled by [`KeyTake`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyTake.html):

```
KeyTake[as, 1]
```

> `<|1->2.2|>`

Also works with multiple "selections":

```
KeyTake[as, {1, 3}]
```

> `<|1 -> 2.2, 3 -> 8.1|>`

Answer (score 6):

The difference could be related to the fact that `Part` (`as[[1]]`) treats associations transparently while `as[[1;;1]]` (i.e. `as[[1~Span~1]]`) is equivalent to `Take[as[1,1]]`, and `Take` does not treat associations transparently.